# Why Solve and Simplify give different results?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I want to solve the following equation

```
y == (1/(1/4 + y) - 1/(3/4 - y))/((1/4 + y) + 1/(3/4 - y))
```

I tried

```
Simplify[y == (1/(1/4 + y) - 1/(3/4 - y))/((1/4 + y) + 1/(3/4 - y)), y]
```

which gave me

> Solve[0.166667]

Then I tried

```
Solve[y == (1/(1/4 + y) - 1/(3/4 - y))/((1/4 + y) + 1/(3/4 - y)), y]
```

which gave me

> {{y -> 1.70683179538858`}, {y -> -0.82623525169495` + 0.902601424800742`I},
>
>     {y -> -0.82623525169495` - 0.902601424800742`I}, {y -> 0.195638708001323`}}

I guess `Simplify` deletes potential roots, but `Solve` and `Simplify` didn't even have an overlap in the roots.

Any idea?

Comment: Check the syntax of `Simplify`.  You're assuming `y`.  Also check that `y` has not been defined.  I do not get the same output as you.  Further, `Simplify` will not yield solutions.  Perhaps you want `Reduce`?

Comment: That's a creative syntax you used with Simplify :) Simplify is not for solving equations, please check the docs for how it's supposed to be used and for the correct syntax.

Comment: What I actually get from Simplify is `True == (32 - 128 True)/(19 + 84 True + 16 True^2 - 64 True^3)`.  The reason for this is that the second argument of Simplify is an assumption.  Assuming `y` means assuming that `y === True` for Mathematica.  This is meaningful when `y` is part of a logical expression such as `x && (y || z)`.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the documentation of [Simplify](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html). I clearly states, that it only simplifies expression:

> performs a sequence of algebraic and other transformations on expr, and returns the simplest form it finds.

When you want to solve your equation your first thought should be `Solve` or `Reduce` and in some other cases maybe `NSolve` or `FindRoot`, depending on what your problem is and what you try to achieve.

`Reduce` tries to solve your equation analytically and gives you additionally required conditions for a solution. Therefore, this should be your first try

```
Reduce[y == (1/(1/4 + y) - 1/(3/4 - y))/((1/4 + y) + 1/(3/4 - y)), y]
(*
 y == Root[32 - 147 #1 - 84 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 64 #1^4 &, 1] || 
 y == Root[32 - 147 #1 - 84 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 64 #1^4 &, 2] || 
 y == Root[32 - 147 #1 - 84 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 64 #1^4 &, 3] || 
 y == Root[32 - 147 #1 - 84 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 64 #1^4 &, 4]
*)
```

You see your equation has 4 solutions which are the roots of the polynomial $$32 - 147 y - 84 y^2 - 16 y^3 + 64 y^4.$$ You can verify that by subtracting `y` on both sides of your equation

```
0 == (1/(1/4 + y) - 1/(3/4 - y))/((1/4 + y) + 1/(3/4 - y)) - y
```

If you use `Together` on this equation you get $$0=\frac{-64 y^4+16 y^3+84 y^2+147 y-32}{(4 y+1) \left(16 y^2-8
   y-19\right)}$$
and you see that the exact same polynomial appears in the numerator. To get numeric values of your solutions you can apply `N` to the `Root` expressions or you use `Solve` like you did in the first place

```
Reduce[y == (1/(1/4 + y) - 1/(3/4 - y))/((1/4 + y) + 1/(3/4 - y)), y] // N
(*
 y == 0.195639 || 
 y == 1.70683 || 
 y == -0.826235 - 0.902601 I ||
 y == -0.826235 + 0.902601 I
*)
```

Comment: This is really great answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: But if simplify returns the simplest form it finds, then at least the simplest solution should be included in the whole set of solutions found by solve?

Comment: @user31321 But `Simplify` does not *solve* an equation. From your above form 0=f(y), what you try to achieve is an explicit solution in y, e.g. y=0.19. `Simplify` does not provide you that.